# active menu when fixed div scrolled

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make the menu that active when page scroll.

This is what I tried so far.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        
        //smoothscroll
        $('.menu a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(document).off("scroll");
            
            $('a').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            $(this).addClass('active');
          
            var target = this.hash,
                menu = target;
            $target = $(target);
            $('.wrap_scroll').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
            }, 500, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });
    });

    function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('.menu a').each(function () {
            var currLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
                $('.menu ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
```

```css
  body, html {  margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 3000px; }
    .menu {   width: 100px; position: fixed;  top:10px; left:10px; }  
    .menu  a.active { background:red }


    .wrap_scroll { position:fixed ; top:20px; left:150px; width:500px; height:400px; overflow-y:scroll }
    #home {  background-color: #286090;  height: 200px; }
    #portfolio {  background: gray; height: 600px; } 
    #about { background-color: blue; height: 800px; }
    #contact {   background:yellow; height: 300px; }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="menu"> 
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>   </li>
      </ul> 
    </div>


    <div class="wrap_scroll"> 
      <div id="home">hh</div>
      <div id="portfolio">pp</div>
      <div id="about">aa</div>
      <div id="contact">cc</div> 
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tkbuq7z/)

The problem is if the div(page) is position fixed, page scrolling is not working smoothly. And the navigation active is not working too.

What do I need to change the code?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind scroll event on `$('.wrap_scroll')` rather than `document` because you are scrolling `wrap_scroll` div rather than whole document, i have modified your code snipet little bit

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.wrap_scroll').bind("scroll",onScroll);
        
        //smoothscroll
        $('.menu a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(document).off("scroll");
            
            $('a').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            $(this).addClass('active');
          
            var target = this.hash,
                menu = target;
            $target = $(target);
            $('.wrap_scroll').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
            }, 500, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });
        function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('.menu a').each(function () {
            var currLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
                $('.menu ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
    });
```

```css
body, html {  margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 3000px; }
    .menu {   width: 100px; position: fixed;  top:10px; left:10px; }  
    .menu  a.active { background:red }


    .wrap_scroll { position:fixed ; top:20px; left:150px; width:500px; height:400px; overflow-y:scroll }
    #home {  background-color: #286090;  height: 200px; }
    #portfolio {  background: gray; height: 600px; } 
    #about { background-color: blue; height: 800px; }
    #contact {   background:yellow; height: 300px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="menu"> 
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>   </li>
      </ul> 
    </div>


    <div class="wrap_scroll"> 
      <div id="home">hh</div>
      <div id="portfolio">pp</div>
      <div id="about">aa</div>
      <div id="contact">cc</div> 
    </div>
```